# Is MainScreen compulsory in BlackBerry applications?

Tags: user-interface, api, blackberry

Currently I've got 2 screens utilizing almost the same functionality and I'd rather extract common logic into some base class but the extend different RIM UI clases: MainScreen and FullScreen. Due to there's no multiple inheritance in java I cant figure out how to do this unless they both extend FullScreen. So the question stated in title arises. I've tested with 4.2 simulator and it works ok without the MainScreen, but I'm not sure for all the OS's out there. Does anyone know?

Cross-posts:

[http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Is-MainScreen-compulsory-in-BlackBerry-applications/td-p/383883](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/211205-mainscreen-compulsory-blackberry-applications.html#post1511361)

http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/211205-mainscreen-compulsory-blackberry-applications.html#post1511361

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, no it is not mandatory to have MainScreen in Blackberry applications.

Comment: +1, MainScreen is useful, since it has basic layout with title, but not mandatory. Moreover, sometime the only solution to implement complex layout is to use FullScreen.

Comment: In my case I use FullScreens throughout the app and the first screen looked different(a bit but still), which ruined consistency. Complex layout is my case :)

Answer (score 1):

MAIN screen is not compulsory, we should use main screen only when we have to provide UI to the users. SO, its not mandatory.